# How to test upload speed?

Tags: internet

There are many symbols for understanding internet-related properties: `$NetworkConnected`, `PingTime`, `NetworkPacketTrace`, `NetworkPacketRecording`, etc.

But is there any convenient way of testing your network's upload speed from within Mathematica?

Answer (score 10):

The easiest method I can think of to get an estimate is to upload a file to a server and measure how long it takes. Should give a reasonable guess, but like all of these things, it can only be a guess. In this example latency to WRI's servers may add a lot.

```
file = "mytestfile";

time = AbsoluteTiming[CopyFile[file, CloudObject["speedtest"]]]
```

> `34.2041`

```
size = FileSize[file]
```

> `Quantity[98.5052, "Megabytes"]`

```
speed = size/Quantity[time, "Seconds"]
```

> `Quantity[2.72684, ("Megabytes")/("Seconds")]`

So in this case it gives my speed as `2.72MB/s`. This is reasonably close to my actual upload speed of `5MB/s`. I re-ran and it gave me `4.74MB/s`, which is pretty on the money. You could use `RepeatedTiming` instead of `AbsoluteTiming` to give a better estimate, but how long you want to run for and the size of the file is pretty much up to you.

You can replace `CloudObject` with `RemoteFile`, an `scp` or `ftp` link, a `Url` and other options described in the documentation if you don't have a Wolfram Cloud account. This also allows you to control for the download speed of the server you're sending the file to.

Comment: This depends on having a wolfram cloud account connected though

Comment: Fair enough, but you could do it this way with any remote server or file upload repository. If you have a remote server you have access to, do `RemoteFile` instead of `CloudObject`. Or the second argument could be an scp link, or ftp, etc.

Comment: I updated my answer to add those details.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way. Install the speedtest cli application for your OS from [here](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli).

```
SetEnvironment["PATH" -> Environment["PATH"] <> "path to install dir"]

output = RunProcess[{"speedtest", "-fcsv", "--output-header"}, "StandardOutput"];

output // ImportString[#, "CSV"] & // 
  Part[#, All, 3 ;; -2] & (* Remove personal info *) //
  Dataset
```

[image]